# PHP script printing unnecessary new lines

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, newline

I'm actually working on a booking system in PHP and I created a script that searches a MySql database checking if a X day is occupied (or not) storing un-occupied dates in an array. After that, I return the array to a function that prints all dates, passing those dates to a jQuery Datepicker array variable, so Datepicker knows which date it should display. The thing is, when I print this array, it prints A LOT OF new lines before starts printing the dates itself.

This is the code that prints the array in the html file:

```
var datasDisponiveis = 
<?php
    if (!(isset($_SESSION["dias"]))) {
        $_SESSION["dias"] = datasDisp();
    }
    echo "["; imprimeDatas($_SESSION["dias"]); echo "];";
?>
```

Translation: dias = days, datasDisp = function that create de available dates array, imprimeDatas = printDates (some portuguese class as bonus lol)

Here is datasDisp():

```
function datasDisp () {
 include "conecta.php";

 $consulta = "SELECT id,mes,dia,ano FROM agenda";
 $data = mysql_query($consulta,$conexao);
 $vetordata = mysql_fetch_array($data);

 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domingo";
 $horas_disponiveis = mysql_query($sql,$conexao);
 $vetor= mysql_fetch_array($horas_disponiveis);

 $semana = array('domingo'=>0,'segunda'=>0,'terça'=>0,'quarta'=>0,'quinta'=>0,'sexta'=>0,'sabado'=>0);

 foreach ($semana as $dia => $valor) {
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $dia";
  $horas_disponiveis = mysql_query($sql,$conexao);
  $vetor= mysql_fetch_array($horas_disponiveis);
  $semana[$dia] = $vetor[0];
 }

 $atual = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));

 $atual->modify('+10 day');

 $final = dataFinal();
 $i = 0;
 $j = 1;
 while ($atual->format('j/n/Y') != $final) {
  $ver_atual = explode("/",$atual->format('j/n/Y'));
  $dia_s = dia_semana($ver_atual[0],$ver_atual[1],$ver_atual[2]);
  if (verificaDataDisponivel($ver_atual[0],$ver_atual[1],$ver_atual[2],$semana[$dia_s])) {
   $datad[$i] = $atual->format('n/j/Y');
   $i++;
  }
  $atual->modify('+1 day');
 }
 return $datad;
}
```

And imprimeDatas():

```
function imprimeDatas ($datas) {
 foreach ($datas as $dia => $valor) {
 echo "'".$datas[$dia]."', ";
 }
}
```

I hope it's not too confusing to understand.

What's printing:

```
var datasDisponiveis = 




































































































['9/24/2010', '9/25/2010', '9/26/2010', '9/27/2010', '9/28/2010', '9/29/2010', '9/30/2010', '10/1/2010', '10/2/2010', '10/3/2010', '10/4/2010', '10/5/2010', '10/6/2010', '10/7/2010', '10/8/2010', '10/9/2010', '10/10/2010', '10/11/2010', '10/12/2010', '10/13/2010', '10/14/2010', '10/15/2010', '10/16/2010', '10/17/2010', '10/18/2010', '10/19/2010', '10/20/2010', '10/21/2010', '10/22/2010', '10/23/2010', '10/24/2010', '10/25/2010', '10/26/2010', '10/27/2010', '10/28/2010', '10/29/2010', '10/30/2010', '10/31/2010', '11/1/2010', '11/2/2010', '11/3/2010', '11/4/2010', '11/5/2010', '11/6/2010', '11/7/2010', '11/8/2010', '11/9/2010', '11/10/2010', '11/11/2010', '11/12/2010', '11/13/2010', '11/14/2010', '11/15/2010', '11/16/2010', '11/17/2010', '11/18/2010', '11/19/2010', '11/20/2010', '11/21/2010', '11/22/2010', '11/23/2010', '11/24/2010', '11/25/2010', '11/26/2010', '11/27/2010', '11/28/2010', '11/29/2010', '11/30/2010', '12/1/2010', '12/2/2010', '12/3/2010', '12/4/2010', '12/5/2010', '12/6/2010', '12/7/2010', '12/8/2010', '12/9/2010', '12/10/2010', '12/11/2010', '12/12/2010', '12/13/2010', '12/14/2010', '12/15/2010', '12/16/2010', '12/17/2010', '12/18/2010', '12/19/2010', '12/20/2010', '12/21/2010', '12/22/2010', '12/23/2010', '12/24/2010', '12/25/2010', '12/26/2010', '12/27/2010', '12/28/2010', '12/29/2010', '12/30/2010', ];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probably want to do something to suppress that last , in your array.

Comment: You can change `imprimeDatas` call to a simple `implode(", ", $_SESSION["dias"])`.

Comment: I tried changing, but it printed all of the new lines but no date.

Comment: Oops, my bad. You need `echo implode...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that this include file is printing out blank lines:

```
include "conecta.php";
```

I would double check to make sure there are no blank lines and/or spaces outside of the `<?php ?>` tags in that file.

Comment: Well, that dataDisp function is within another archive which is a function library that has a bunch of functions. Each of these functions has an include "conecta.php";, which I think it's dumb (this is a legacy code, I didn't write myself) but I'm in a hurry to release the system. Anyways, I tried to remove every new line from conecta.php, but it didn't work.

Comment: I doubled checked here and indeed it had 2 new lines at the end here. I removed it and it worked! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: It's a good practice to leave the closing php tag off, so additional newlines at the end of the file won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, strange...

Maybe this helps:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION["dias"])) { $_SESSION["dias"] = datasDisp(); }
    echo "var datasDisponiveis = [".imprimeDatas($_SESSION['dias'])."];";
?>
```

Comment: It didn't, here's the output: <new lines> <dates> , var datasDisponiveis = [];

Comment: It must be in `conecta.php` as MacAnthony suggests. Can you post that code too?

Comment: Yep, it was there. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your code (either the main program or any include file) has any white space either before the beginning "<?php" tag or after the ending "?>" tag, you will get spurious blank lines in your output.

This is quite a common error, especially at the end of the file, so check all your includes and remove any unnecessary spaces or blank lines at the top and bottom.

Comment: What some of the libraries archives have before de <?php is a javascript function defined. Would that be a problem?